# three.js: access canvas size in custom shader

Tags: three.js

Do [built-in uniforms](http://threejs.org/docs/api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.html) for vertex shader in three.js, namely:

```
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
```

contain information about the window size or at least the aspect ratio?

For now I'm passing the size as additional vec2 uniform and I'm just wondering if it's redundant.